# What does 'would' mean following 'certainly'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> We certainly wouldn't advise you to approach the site yourself.
>   (Source: [BBC, The Archers, 2013-04-19 Friday, 5’40”](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/archers).)

What's the meaning of *would* when it follows *certainly*? *Would* might produce uncertainty, I guess; then, why does it follow *certainly*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Would* is employed as it is in conditional constructions, to imply unreality. There is no explicit condition expressed, but sentences like this imply either a condition which is supplied by the context or what you might call a "universal condition" (don't quote that, it's a term I just made up):

> EXPLICIT CONDITIONAL: Under these circumstances we would do such-and-such.
>   IMPLICIT CONDITIONAL: [Under the circumstances previously mentioned] we would do such-and-such.
>   UNIVERSAL CONDITIONAL: [Under **any** circumstances] we would do such-and-such.

*Certainly* modifies the entire sentence, thus emphasizing the negation which is its core. It might equally be written:

> Certainly, we would not advise you to approach the site yourself.
>   We would certainly not advise you to approach the site yourself.

So what the sentence amounts to is either:

> IMPLICIT CONDITIONAL: It is certain that [under the present circumstances] we would not advise you to approach the site yourself.
>   *OR*
>   UNIVERSAL CONDITIONAL: It is certain that there is **no** circumstance under which we would advise you to approach the site yourself.

Comment: Isn't it perfectly reasonable to assume that the "implied circumstances" simply amount to *if you were to ask our advice*?