# difference between "would" and "will"

Tags: will-would

I am having a hard time deciding "will" or "would": Which one I should use in the contexts?

1- "I ***would/will definitely*** love to move into a decent place."

2- "I ***would/will definitely*** like to visit Paris next year."

I always use would with these words. But the problem is with the word "definitely". Should I use "would" or "will" definitely? I think "will definitely love" and "will definitely like" sound unnatural. Isn't it? And one more questions, Could someone please suggest some more words that can mostly be used with "would"?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but you should look here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102460/usage-of-the-subjunctive-word-would?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

"**I would definitely love to move into a decent place**" means that you're not yet sure that you'll be able to move into a decent place (or maybe you even know that you won't be able to), but you'd definitely love to.

"**I would definitely like to visit Paris next year**" means that you're not sure that you'll be able to visit Paris next year, but you'd definitely love to.

"Definitely" here means that you are sure that you want to.  It doesn't mean that the condition itself is certain to be fulfilled - only that you are certain to be pleased if the condition is met.

"**I will definitely love to move into a decent place**" means that you know that you'll be moving into a decent place, and you'll definitely love it.  However, it sounds slightly unnatural.  You'd be more likely to say "*I'll definitely love moving into a decent place*" and even more likely to say "*I'll definitely love living in a decent place*" or "*I'll definitely love being in a decent place*".

"**I will definitely like to visit Paris next year**" is a slightly unnatural way to say that you're going to visit Paris next year and will definitely like it.  You'd be more likely to say "*I'll definitely enjoy visiting Paris next year*" or "*I'm definitely going to like visiting Paris next year*".

Comment: Maybe use the definition "without doubt" instead of repeating definitely when explaining the difference in the middle of your answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer.